# SOAP request modification

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a SOAP request like this, it's working fine:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <web:ConversionRate>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <FromCurrency>?</FromCurrency>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ToCurrency>?</ToCurrency>
  </web:ConversionRate>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I was changing the request a litle bit to understand the concepts:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ConversionRate xmlns="http://com/">>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <FromCurrency>?</FromCurrency>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ToCurrency>?</ToCurrency>
  </ConversionRate>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The second one is not working, throwing a wrong answer.

My service class is

```
package com; 
import javax.jws.WebService;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;


 @WebService (targetNamespace="http://com/") 
 public class CurrencyConvertor
 { 
 public String ConversionRate (@WebParam(name = "FromCurrency") String FromCurrency, @WebParam(name = "ToCurrency")  String ToCurrency)
 { 
System.out.println("ST\n" +  FromCurrency + "\n" + ToCurrency + "\nEnd" );
switch(FromCurrency+","+ToCurrency)
{
case "USD,INR":
 return "58";

case "INR,USD":
 return "0.017";

default:
return "XXX";

}
}
}
```

The second request always falling to default case, the thing is, the values are sending as null since I changed the name space. So my Web service should answer for the second request properly, what should cause the issue, how to rectify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your namespace is not correct even it looks well. 
I have to change com to com.example, because it is not possible to post answer with link to com only.

tns=http://com.example/ is defined in 
the WebService, not for the webmethod. Change your method declaration to

```
public String ConversionRate (
    @WebParam(name = "FromCurrency", tagetNamespace = "http://com.example/") String FromCurrency, 
    @WebParam(name = "ToCurrency", tagetNamespace = "http://com.example/")  String ToCurrency) { 

    ... 

}
```

Even I'm not definitely sure if the XML has valid format

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ConversionRate xmlns="http://com.example/">
     <FromCurrency>?</FromCurrency>
     <ToCurrency>?</ToCurrency>
  </ConversionRate>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

or namespace is required just for parameters

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ConversionRate>
     <FromCurrency xmlns="http://com.example/">?</FromCurrency>
     <ToCurrency xmlns="http://com.example/">?</ToCurrency>
  </ConversionRate>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```